# How to keep track of backlinks?

Tags: backlinks, sharepoint

I am operating an internal website to which other internal websites are linking through deep-links. Currently, when I alter my website, I go out and search for corresponding links other sites, and try to update them or inform the webmaster.

I'm searching for an efficient workflow to help me keep track of the inbound links, so that I can change the links. I cannot run link-checkers on the other websites, but in terms of attracting visitors it is in my own interest to keep the inbound links up to date.

My website is sitting in Sharepoint. I was thinking of keeping a spreadsheet with all the links and pages they are on. Another option just occurred to me: check in the Sharepoint logs for calls to dead links together with the originating (referrer URL) and the go and fix it (basically "on demand")... but I don't know how to do it in Sharepoint 2013.

Any suggestion/idea is most welcome. Maybe there is even a software for this task.

Comment: I disagree, but I have to accept. Every answer, script and solution is opinionated. Even the choice of asking this forum is based on my opinion to get good advice.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like you are going about this the wrong way.
You have access over your site, but not the other sites.

It would seem more sensible to set up redirects of any pages you move.  That way, any link pointing to the old page would find themselves on the new page without having to update their links.

301 links are best, but since internal sites presumably have no need for SEO, you could also use meta refresh or javascript to achieve this.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How can I do this in Sharepoint?

Comment: This thread seems to give a few ways - http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/51604/immediate-redirect-page-in-sharepoint

Comment: I totally agree with you that the approach should be to apply the changes to my own site, and catch links to outdated sites. And I would do this for every site out on the open web. However, I am living in the luxurious situation of being able to change neighboring sites. For the sake of simplicity, we could say that the other sites are also maintained by me. So why should I not change the wrong links? Anyway, maybe keeping track of all the links on a site is just a tedious job, and cannot be replaced by a tool. :-(

Comment: No reason not to do it manually, it is just the amount of effort that could be replaced by a simple script seems a waste of time.